# IE7 shows header different

Tags: internet-explorer-7

My header looks totally different in IE7.

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT**

Link to site; http://tinyurl.com/3g58vhb

Comment: To see the issue, we need to see the website (HTML & CSS)

Comment: IE7 has major issues with `floats` in CSS, especially `float:right`. If you could let us see the website itself or your CSS for the header we can help.

Comment: Here is the link http://tinyurl.com/3g58vhb